Android 14 Settings.System.canWrite after restart always false
In my App it's need to edit settings to change SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT for make screen always active and full brightness. I use code for get permittions:
if (!Settings.System.canWrite(this)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivity(intent);
        }

It's work fine but when user restart device it's make reqest permittions again. Please help: how to fix it? Thanks
I find some info that it's need to make sign APK by system keys, I try to use apksigner and key/cert from here  but it didn't help
